# Material-UI AutoComlete only load values on second click

Tags: node.js, reactjs, material-ui

On my react app I have 3 droplist
the first drop has the primary values ​​(ex: a, b) the next drop will filter the values ​​in the array using the value selected in the first drop
I'm using the ui and Autocomplete material for the dropboxes
when I select the value in the first drop the component returns the value in the event of the click to the parent, and then I call the second drop with these values

```
<Grid item xs={4}>
          <Dropdownlist
            required
            name='opt1'
            texto='where:'
            click={click1}
            options={options}
            optionsList1={optionsList1}
            filter='regiao'
          />
        </Grid>
        <Grid item xs={4}>
          {optionNameShow2 === 'hidden' ? null
            : <Dropdownlist
              required
              name='opt2'
              select3='hidden'
              texto='&nbsp;'
              click={click2}
              options={options2}
              valueforFilter={selectState1 ? selectState1.optionValue : ''}
              optionsList2={optionsList2}
              filter='local'
              />}
        </Grid>
```

the problem is that the values ​​are only loading when I click the second time.

the probleme is on chrome and FF so far tested
and shoud be on first click.

working exemple is on : https://codesandbox.io/s/muddy-haze-6c1kj?file=/src/App.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**TL;DR:** Your `filterlists()` triggers a state change, but `if (value) {...` is using the values before that call changes are actually reflected in the current state. I fixed your [pastebin](https://codesandbox.io/s/dropbox-probleme-forked-63z00?file=/src/comp/Dropdownlist.jsx).

**NL;PR:** `setStates` are scheduled to run after the function that calls them ends, thus the values you are currently using are still before the changes have taken place. Take care of those `setStates` separately with an effect hook.

Comment: you are the best, really tanks for the help